# Use Macrium Reflect to Clone an SSD with three partitions to a larger SSD, expanding the middle partition

Tags: partitioning, ssd, disk-cloning, macrium

I'm trying to use Macrium Reflect Free to clone a disk from a 75 GB SSD to 225 GB SSD. The source has three partitions, and I want to clone them all, but I want the first and third to be the same size, and the middle one to be expanded to fill the remaining space on the drive.

In this screen capture, I have (1) added the first and second partition and (2) expanded the second partition, leaving 50 GB of free space.

[image: There is clearly 50 GB of available space]

When I click "Copy selected partitions", it should add the third partition (which is only 9.76 GB) into the remaining 50 GB of space, but I get this:

[image: Error dialog indicating insufficient space]

How can there be insufficient space?

I should mention that this is what I get if I try to copy the first and third partitions first:

[image: There is a gap between the partitions]

It seems to be forcing the partitions to be placed in the same location as they were on the source, but why?

**Primary question:** How can I accomplish my goal of cloning these three partitions, with the middle one expanded to fill the free space on the disk?

Comment: *Why* it's doing it is probably something that can best be answered by the devs.

Comment: @Karan, good point, I reworded my question.

Comment: What happens if you copy the first partition as-is, and the second expanded, and only once those two are done, *then* copy the third to the remaining space? Of course, you can also copy all 3 as-is, then resize as required later using GParted or similar.

Comment: @Karan, I actually tried (1) cloning as is, (2) deleting the third partition using Disk Management, (3) expanding the second partition to all but 10 GB using Disk Management, and (4) cloning just the third partition using Macrium Reflect. I still get this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9TP0v.png. So, it's still trying to put that third partition in the same location.

Answer (score 1):

I would image the drive as it is to the new SSD.  Then, use a partitioning tool, like  [EASEUS Free Partition Master](http://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/personal.html) to resize and move the partitions – it should do it for you very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

- Drag down the first two partitions, select the second one, click on cloned partitioned properties.
- Resize the second partition so as to leave just enough room for the third.
- Click O.K.
- Now drag down the third partition.
- At this point you should be all set to clone.

**Note:** When you are in partition properties, for partition 2 you can just type in the third partition size where it says free space on the left side.

Comment: This is for restoring an image, not cloning the hard drive. That should be noted in this answer.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this same issue.  If you select all three partitions and then click 'Copy selected partitions' you will only be able to resize the last partition.  If you select the first two partitions, click copy, resize the second, then select the third and click copy again, it will complain that there is not enough space.  However, if you instead click and drag the partition, it works.  I suspect the 'Copy selected partition' button is attempting to copy all three partitions, not simply adding the third partition.